# Anyway to have an action be anything in the RouteConfig in MVC and not having to specify a specific one?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

So I have a controller that holds about 10 actions. Each action/view just simply holds an image. What I'm trying to do is have a parameter sent to the URL for each action (the parameter does the same thing for each action).

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "MyRoute",
                url: "MyController/{action}/{myparameter}",
                defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "CanIMakeThisBeAnything", myparameter = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Is there anyway I can make the action take in any action in the controller so I don't have to specify 10 different routes?

Comment: What do your actions look like?

Comment: It is not at all clear to me why you think you need 10 different routes. The only action you're specifying in the code above is the default action.

Comment: Are you getting an error of some kind? From your question I agree with @James R...It doesn't look as though you need to do anything with the routes.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you're just confused about how the route works. The `action` parameter is just a default in the case nothing is specified (i.e. `/MyController/`. If you send the user to the URL `/MyController/Foo/` it will hit the `Foo` action, despite what you set for `action`.

Comment: "The action parameter is just a default" Ahhhhhh that's what I got wrong. I thought the action had to be the specific action for the controller. That makes a lot more sense. Basically the idea is for each action I return a view with a different image. So that looks like "MyController/action". For each action, I wanted another parameter (is that the right phrase?) in the URL that I can grab and use in my code... i.e. "MyController/action/parameter" @ChrisPratt

Comment: @JamesR. I answered in another comment if you'd like to take a look

Comment: @AnthonyMascia sorry it took me a couple days to circle back. I added an answer. I hope it explains what you need.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your comments correctly, you want to make the route look like:

```
        routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}/{myparameter}",
            new 
            { 
                controller = "My",
                action = "CanIMakeThisBeAnything", 
                myparameter = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
```

And your action(s) like:

```
public ActionResult YesYouCanMakeThisAnything(string myparameter)
{
    ...
    return View(...);
}
```

So if someone navigated to **yourwebapp/My/YesYouCanMakeThisAnything/abc123**, then it would call the above action and myparameter would equal "abc123".

If someone navigated to simply **yourwebapp**, then it would call the action named "CanIMakeThisBeAnything" (specified in your defaults for the route) on the controller "MyController" (also specified in your defaults for the route) and myparameter would equal null (because it has no default and is optional).

Comment: This is a confusing answer, and I don't think it answers the asker's question clearly.  My reading of this answer is, "No, and I don't understand your question."  The thing that the asker was asking, was "does the 'action' part of the route mapping have to be specified?" - this question doesn't clearly answer that.